# Need help in fixing prime numbers program

Tags: c++

I am newbie to C++ and I am trying to make a console program that lists prime numbers.I am having problem in getting expected results as it stops after showing

```
2 is a prime number
```

which is wrong and list is not complete.PLease review my code and help me fix it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num,divi,count=0;

    for(num=0;num<10;num++)
    {   
        for(divi=1;divi<=num;divi++)
        {

            if(num%divi==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if(count==2){
                 cout<<num<<"is a prime number"<<endl;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize count each time when a new number is checked. And the second if statement has to be placed outside the inner loop.
For example

```
for(num=0;num<10;num++)
{
    count = 0;   
    for(divi=1;divi<=num;divi++)
    {

        if(num%divi==0){count++;}
    }

    if(count==2){cout<<num<<"is a prime number"<<endl;}

}
```

Take into account that 2 is a prime number.

Also it is not a good idea to declare variables in a declarative region where they are not used. I would write the program like

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int num = 0; num < N; num++ )
    {
        int count = 0;

        for ( int div = 1; div <= num; div++ )
        {
            count += num % div == 0;
        }

        if ( count == 2 ) std::cout << num << " is a prime number" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or instead of

```
count += num % div == 0;
```

you could write as in your original program

```
if ( num % div == 0 ) ++count;
```

Comment: Many thanks!! but is there any other more efficient method of getting the same results i.e shorter code..

Comment: @Neek  It is enough to check divisors that are satisfy condition divisor * divisor <= num

Comment: I guess num < N/2 will make it a bit quick for large numbers. Any divisor should be there in 1 to n/2 range.

Comment: @Abdullah Leghari divisor * divisor <= num is a more accurate condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset count to 0 at the start of each iteration of your outer for loop.  You may as well just declare count there to begin with.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to learn to use a debugger (e.g. gdb)

Answer (score 0):

You fail to reset `count` after the first check, so it starts at `2` when you check the number 3

You should reset the count each iteration:

```
for(num=0;num<10;num++)
{  
    count = 0;
    ... // Rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but why 4,8,9 are also showing as prime numbers.Please suggest a fix to my logic.EDIT:thanks....FIXED IT